# My 404 not found page with React router is not working

Tags: reactjs

My "404 not found page" with React router is not working.
This is how I use Router(v6):

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='*' element={<Notfound/>} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage/>} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<Aboutpage/>} />
      <Route path="/picture" element={<Picturepage/>} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<Projectpage/>} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

The "Not found" element is the page I'm looking for, but it seems it doesn't work for me.
In the Notfound.js I wrote like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const Notfound = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Notfound'>404 Notfound</div>
  )
}

export default Notfound
```

I imported the page, but I can't fix this. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Please put down not found router. Not found must be last element in routes.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your Notfound page path like below

```
<Route path='/*' element={<Notfound/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<Route path='/*' element={<Notfound/>} >`

Comment: This is not right solution. Check documentation for not found route

Comment: @NijatAliyev idk this works fine when I tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your NotFound Path

```js
<Route path = '/*' element = {<NotFound />}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).